# Power BI issues with Incapsula

Tags: header, powerbi, incapsula

I'm trying to get data->web to a service that uses Incapsula for DDOS and I'm getting the error:

> DataSource.Error: The server committed a protocol violation.
>   Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF

There was a workaround posted here:
[Power BI (Power Query) Web request results in "CR must be followed by LF" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838007/power-bi-power-query-web-request-results-in-cr-must-be-followed-by-lf-error)

But that workaround won't work for me, as the data that is returned is not a Web.Page (rather it's JSON) and therefore the Web.Page function will return a message that the results don't look like a Web.page.

Query looks like this:

```
= Json.Document(Web.Contents("url", [Headers=[Authorization="Basic {encoded value}", #"X-Forte-Auth-Organization-Id"="{org_id}"]]))
```

and will actually work when I use the query validator, but when I exit out to use I get the error shown above.

If I do this:

```
=Json.Document(Web.Page(Web.Contents(url, [Headers=[Authorization="Basic {encoded value}", #"X-Forte-Auth-Organization-Id"="{org_id}"]])))
```

then I get this error:

> DataFormat.Error: The resource at 'url' cannot be retrieved using
>   Web.Page. It doesn't appear to be a web page.

Stack overflow wouldn't let me post the actual urls because I don't have enough reputation.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Disclaimer: I work for Incapsula]

I recommend contacting Incapsula support at support[at]incapsula.com

They can help you with this, but are unable to post the response publically.

Comment: Thanks Avi!  - Will do

Comment: Great. Sorry for posting an answer to go to support, because that's always a good first step.